# How to convert a tricky ereg_replace to preg_replace?

Tags: php, posix-ere

I know there are lots of questions on that but i didn't found anything matches with my question. I want to convert this expression to preg_replace:

```
$a = ereg_replace('[-a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+@([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*','', $a);
```

so far tried those but didn't worked:

```
$a = ereg_replace('/[-a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+@([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*/','', $a);
$a = ereg_replace('|[-a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~]+@([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*|','', $a);
```

Here is the error message for second line:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '}' in
```

Comment: Try `preg_quote`ing the stuff in your character class.

Comment: In the second one, you are using the delimiter inside the pattern without quoting it (just before the `}`)

Comment: Escape the delimiter. Or use a delimiter which doesn't occur in your character list, e.g. `°`. If all else fails `preg_match("\001[....]\001"` is always an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the character that delimits the match string, use something that's not in the match string, or escaping the uses of the delimiter within the string, like

```
$a = ereg_replace('/[-a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~]+@([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_\/-])*/','', $a);
```

That particular example is kind of hard to read; I'd find a character that's not used at all.